# Array list and list view

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

Im trying to get data from json. Actually it is working but i have a problem with listview.Im getting error.

[image: Here is the error image]

Here is the code;
MainActivity.java

```js
  

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView txt;
    Places places=new Places();
    ListView listView;
    List<Places> PlacesList=new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        new getData().execute("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=41,29&oauth_token=01ZV1VDLE41USSRAYJUXOWNJ2MXYCAVN1I2PQFLFBCD40XYI&v=20160304");

    }
    public class getData extends AsyncTask<String,String,List <Places>> {
        HttpURLConnection conn=null;
        URL url=null;
        BufferedReader bReader=null;
        String name=null;
        @Override
        protected List<Places> doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                //BURADA URL'E BAGLANDIK
                url=new URL(params[0]);
                conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                //VERİ OKUMAK İÇİN STREAM KULLANACAZ
                InputStream istream=conn.getInputStream();
                bReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
                //VERİ DEPOLAMAK İÇİN StringBuffer
                StringBuffer sBuffer=new StringBuffer();
                String line="";
                while((line=bReader.readLine())!=null){
                    sBuffer.append(line);
                }
                String JSONFinal=sBuffer.toString();
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(JSONFinal);
                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("venues");
                StringBuffer finalBuffer=new StringBuffer();
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject finalJsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    name = finalJsonObject.getString("name");
                    places.setName(name);
                    PlacesList.add(places);
                }

                return  PlacesList;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( List<Places> PlacesList) {
            super.onPostExecute(PlacesList);
            ArrayAdapter adapter=  new ArrayAdapter<Places>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,PlacesList);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }
```

Places.java

```js
public class Places {
    int id,lat,lng;
    String name;



    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

So what is the problem?

Comment: post your json also.

Comment: here is my json http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?url=https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=41,29&oauth_token=01ZV1VDLE41USSRAYJUXOWNJ2MXYCAVN1I2PQFLFBCD40XYI&v=20160304

Comment: i dont be able to see any string called name in your json.

Comment: @Azat  Check my answer.

Comment: go to response>venues>0>name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It displays like that because you have passed `Places` object to your list view, and  you haven't provided which fields to show in your list view from `Places` object , you should probably provide `toString()` method in your `Places` object to see your list with name or you should create your own adapter implementation

To see your listview with names

add this in your `Places` class

```
public void toString(){
return name;
}
```

Comment: @Azat  You can mark this as answer by clicking the right mark beside the answer if it helps you, so that it will help for others facing the same issue

Comment: Its done. I have one more question. How am i gonna show all the places. It this way all the names are same

Comment: @Azat I see you marking somebody's answer as correct answer. You should probably create your custom Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you haven't overridden the `toString()` method of your `Places` class.

Add this to your `Places` class:

```
@Override
public String toString(){

 return name;
}
```

See if that helps. 
The Adapter is calling the `toString()` method of `Places` `Object` superclass, which is returning a hash of the `Places` object.
That's what's being printed.

Comment: I have another question. It shows same name in each item of listview. So what do i need to do?

Comment: You only have one places object, it looks to me like with each iteration of your for loop you're changing the name of that single object, then adding a reference to the same object to the list.

Comment: in the for loop at the end, try Places place = new Places(); place.setName("new name"); then add that to the arraylist.

Comment: Also, you Places class is named a plural, but only handles a single place. You should remove the s from the end of the name.

Comment: Thank you so much it woks. I have some problems with english :)

Comment: Thank you:) its really hard to find anybody can help me in my language. Im trying to be better :)